# For mixed unmanaged and managed C++ code do we need to be compiling with /EHa exception handling? What is the default?

Tags: c++, exception, seh

We have a process with mixed `/clr` (managed) code and unmanaged code and we're trying to determine what exception handling model to use. I think we (might?) need to be using `/EHa`. Right now we're specifying `<ExceptionHandling>Async</ExceptionHandling>` which is the same as compiling with `/EHa` in our C++ project files. This way we catch all exceptions, including structured exceptions, and treat all exceptions as fatal in a top level `catch(...)` block (because they might be access violations or other things that would put the program into an undefined state).

I'm confused reading [/EH (Exception Handling Model)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx), specifically:

> The /EHa compiler option is used to support asynchronous structured
>   exception handling (SEH) with the native C++ catch(...) clause. To
>   implement SEH without specifying /EHa, you may use the __try,
>   __except, and __finally syntax. Although Windows and Visual C++ support SEH, we strongly recommend that you use ISO-standard C++
>   exception handling (/EHs or /EHsc) because it makes code more portable
>   and flexible. Nevertheless, in existing code or for particular kinds
>   of programs—for example, in code compiled to support the common
>   language runtime (/clr (Common Language Runtime Compilation))—you
>   still **might** have to use SEH. For more information, see Structured
>   Exception Handling (C/C++).

This says that we **might** have to use `/EHa`. Then I go up to the top of the page, trying to figure out what the default exception handling model is (and if it is equivalent to `/EHa`), and I'm unsure...it seems very similar but there are slightly different descriptions, the default exception handling model is described as:

> If /EH is not specified, the compiler catches both asynchronous
>   structured exceptions and C++ exceptions, but does not destroy C++
>   objects that go out of scope because of an asynchronous exception.

**Do we need to specify /EHa because we have mixed managed (`/clr`) and unmanged code that must communicate at a point during exception handling?**

**Is the default exception handling model for C++ projects in VS2015 equivalent to `/EHa`?**

Comment: `/EHa` is required for C++/CLI code, so at least some of your code will need to be compiled with this flag. I don't know whether it's even possible to mix files compiled with `/EHs(c)` and `/EHa`, but it sounds risky to me, so I'd personally avoid it.

Comment: @user786653 I don't think it is. It's one flavor or the other. I'm fairly sure if we chose `/EHa`, everything has to be compiled with `/EHa`.

Comment: You have to use /EHa iff you use the non-standard `__try/__except` keywords in your code.  Or `catch(...)` which now catches everything.  Catching and handling a managed exception that way is possible.  But not terribly wise, there is absolutely nothing you can do to *actually* handle it.  You can't even generate a reasonable error message.  The state of the managed code is unpredictable, continuing to call it is risky.  YMMV.